# How to Print two columns of loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a file that has a list of names along with their sex and a count of how many people have the name. I want to print the top 10 female and male names side by side . My issue is when i run my program this is what it prints.

**What is Printing**

```
"Female"    "Male"

  Jacob     Jacob
  Ethan     Ethan
  Michael   Michael
  Jayden    Jayden
  William   William
  Alexander Alexander
  Noah      Noah
  Daniel    Daniel
  Aiden     Aiden
  Anthony   Anthony
```

I want this to print

```
"Female"    "Male"

Isabella     Jacob
Sophia       Ethan
Emma         Michael
Addison      William
Elizabeth    Alexander    
Ella         Joshua
Olivia       Mason
Ava          Evan
Emily        Nicholas
Abigail      Gavin
```

---

```
for (String s : descending())
{

    for (int i = 0 ;i < 10;i++)
    {
    String z = oneName.get(i).getName();

        if('M' == oneName.get(i).getSex())
        {
         System.out.printf("%13.10s%10.10s%n",z, oneName.get(i).getName());

        }
        if('F' == oneName.get(i).getSex())
        {

          z = oneName.get(i).getName();
        }
    }

        break;
}
```

Comment: What does "top 10" mean ? how is `oneName` constructed ? without this information any answer is only a guess... Further, it seems that you're printing only inside the first `if`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time your print something, `z` has always been set to the current name...

```
String z = oneName.get(i).getName();
if('M' == oneName.get(i).getSex())
{
    System.out.printf("%13.10s%10.10s%n",z, oneName.get(i).getName());
```

This would suggest that the female name seems to be coming first.

Assuming that the data comes in female/male order you could do something like...

```
String maleName = null;
String femaleName = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    if ('M' == oneName.get(i).getSex()) {

        maleName = oneName.get(i).getName();

    }
    if ('F' == oneName.get(i).getSex()) {

        femaleName = oneName.get(i).getName();

    }

    if (maleName != null && femaleName != null) {

        System.out.printf("%13.10s%10.10s%n", femaleName, maleName);
        maleName = null;
        femaleName = null;

    }
}
```

But I'm making assumptions about the order in which the data is stored and without evidence to the country, it's difficult to suggest something else

**Updated with a proof of concept**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>(25);
        people.add(new Person("Isabella", 'F'));
        people.add(new Person("Jacob", 'M'));
        people.add(new Person("Sophia", 'F'));
        people.add(new Person("Ethan", 'M'));
        people.add(new Person("Emma", 'F'));
        people.add(new Person("Michael", 'M'));
        people.add(new Person("Addison", 'F'));
        people.add(new Person("William", 'M'));
        people.add(new Person("Elizabeth", 'F'));
        people.add(new Person("Alexander", 'M'));
        people.add(new Person("Ella", 'F'));
        people.add(new Person("Joshua", 'M'));
        people.add(new Person("Olivia", 'F'));
        people.add(new Person("Mason", 'M'));
        people.add(new Person("Ava", 'F'));
        people.add(new Person("Evan", 'M'));
        people.add(new Person("Emily", 'F'));
        people.add(new Person("Nicholas", 'M'));
        people.add(new Person("Abigail", 'F'));
        people.add(new Person("Gavin", 'M'));

        String maleName = null;
        String femaleName = null;
        for (Person p : people) {

            if ('M' == p.getSex()) {

                maleName = p.getName();

            }
            if ('F' == p.getSex()) {

                femaleName = p.getName();

            }

            if (maleName != null && femaleName != null) {

                System.out.printf("%13.10s%10.10s%n", femaleName, maleName);
                maleName = null;
                femaleName = null;

            }
        }
    }

    public static class Person {

        private String name;
        private char sex;

        public Person(String name, char sex) {
            this.name = name;
            this.sex = sex;
        }

        public char getSex() {
            return sex;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }

}
```

Which prints out...

```
 Isabella     Jacob
   Sophia     Ethan
     Emma   Michael
  Addison   William
Elizabeth Alexander
     Ella    Joshua
   Olivia     Mason
      Ava      Evan
    Emily  Nicholas
  Abigail     Gavin
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

```
String z = oneName.get(i).getName();
```

declare the variable z outside the forLoop otherwise it creates new String everytime.

```
String z = null;
for (String s : descending())
{
    for (int i = 0 ;i < 10;i++)
    {
       z = oneName.get(i).getName();
```

Comment: it is now printing each female name multiple times